# How to calculate running total grouped by Order No

Tags: sql-server-2008, cumulative-sum

Trying to create a running total for orders in SQL Server 2008, similar to the below table (Order No & Order Total columns exist in my SQL Server table), tried using a recursive cte but my results were a running total for all orders, not grouped by order no. Any suggestions how to have the running total grouped by the order no? Thanks

```
---------------------------------------------------------
| Order No. | Order Total  | Running Total for Order No |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     1     | $10,000      | $10,000                    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     1     | -$5,000      |  $5,000                    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     1     |  $3,000      |  $8,000                    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     2     |  $2,500      |  $2,500                    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     2     |  $5,000      |  $7,500                    |
---------------------------------------------------------
|     2     |  $4,000      | $11,000                    |
---------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: `SELECT OrderNo, SUM(OrderTotal) FROM TableName GROUP BY OrderNo`

Comment: If you have prices stored as VARCHAR then try this Query: `SELECT OrderNo,SUM(CONVERT(INT,REPLACE(REPLACE(OrderTotal,'$',''),',','')))) FROM TableName GROUP BY OrderNo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do this is with an [Instead of Insert Trigger](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx). The trigger would subtract/add from the groups first value. Obviously this should of been done at the creation of the table but you could add it after you make table update. 
Keep in mind in order for the below code to work, you would need a primary key on the Order table

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
           id           INT IDENTITY(0, 1) PRIMARY KEY
         , orderNo      INT
         , orderTotal   MONEY
         , runningTotal MONEY
);

INSERT INTO Orders
VALUES
(1,10000,10000),
(1,-5000,5000),
(1,3000,8000),
(2,2500,2500),
(2,5000,7500),
(2,4000,11500);

GO

--CREATE TRIGGER

CREATE TRIGGER trg_RunningTotal ON Orders
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @PreviousTotal MONEY =
              (
              SELECT TOP 1
                    a.runningTotal
                    FROM  Orders AS a
                        INNER JOIN INSERTED AS b ON a.orderNo = b.orderNo
                    WHERE a.orderno = b.Orderno
                    ORDER BY a.id DESC
              );
        INSERT INTO Orders
        SELECT
             orderno,
             orderTotal,
             (@PreviousTotal + orderTotal) AS runningTotal
             FROM INSERTED;
    END;

--Insert new record

        INSERT INTO orders
        VALUES
        (1,1000,NULL);

--View newly added record

        SELECT
             *
             FROM  orders
             WHERE orderno = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to following query:

```
    SELECT orderno,
SUM((CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(ordertotal)=1
THEN CONVERT(MONEY,ordertotal) ELSE 0 END)
)
AS [Converted to Numeric]

FROM price group by orderno
```